# Entity framework virtual navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, ef-code-first

I develop web application using EF6.

Say I have the following models:

```
public interface IBaseEntityObject 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}


public abstract class BaseEntityObject : IBaseEntityObject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
}


public class Folder : BaseEntityObject
{   
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public List<Letter> Letters {get; set;} 
}


public abstract class Letter : BaseEntityObject
{   
    public string Title {get; set;}

    public string Content {get; set;}

    public virtual Folder Folder {get; set;}

    public int FolderId {get; set;}

    public DateTime CreationDate {get; set;}
}

public class OutgoingLetter : Letter
{
    // .. OutgoingLetter properties
}

public class ReceviedLetter : Letter
{
    // .. ReceviedLetter properties
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Folder> Folders {get; set;}

    public DbSet<Letter> Letters {get; set;}


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Folder <-> Letters       
        modelBuilder.Entity<Letter>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.Folder)
        .WithMany(f => f.Letters)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.FolderId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

Is there any loss if I remove the virtual Folder navigation property from the Letter model? I don't want my clients to receive a folder when they ask for a letter..seems wrong.

I'm just wondering if by removing this property, I'm losing some EF performance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want my clients to receive a folder when they ask for a
>   letter..seems wrong.

You should not return domain objects to your clients, but *data-transfer objects*. [Check Martin Folwer's definition](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html):

> When you're working with a remote interface, such as Remote Facade
>   (388), each call to it is expensive. As a result you need to reduce
>   the number of calls, and that means that you need to transfer more
>   data with each call. One way to do this is to use lots of parameters.
>   However, this is often awkward to program - indeed, it's often
>   impossible with languages such as Java that return only a single
>   value.
>
> The solution is to create a Data Transfer Object that can hold all the
>   data for the call. It needs to be serializable to go across the
>   connection. Usually an assembler is used on the server side to
>   transfer data between the DTO and any domain objects.

Comment: From what I understand, it means to create another object that will hold the data I want to send to the clients - meaning I'll create another LetterForClients which will only hold for example Title and FolderId?

And regardless, is there any good reason to keep the virtual Folder navigation property?

Comment: If virtual is not used, EF will not be able to fill this property in LazyLoading, when this property will be called.

Comment: And if i set EnableLazyLoading = false? Removing this property will change anything?

Comment: @S.Peter about keeping or not the whole property is up to you, who knows, but anyway you shouldn't return domain objects to your client, it's just a rule to avoid situations like the one you're currently experiencing